# How to set mylocation button to top right corner on google maps for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-maps

I have implemented google maps in a viewcontroller with following code:

```
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
mapView.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

i also want to add another subview on the mapview at bottommost position but its not getting diplayed:

```
UIView *holder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 568, 0, 120)];
holder.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
holder.backgroundColor =
[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:holder];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i think you make the holder view outside of main view, try to make it in main views dimension by reducing the origin y. suppose, 
CGRectMake(320, 400, 0, 120)];

Comment: i updated UIView *holder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 75, 0, 120)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused regarding `CGRectMake`. The first argument is the x, the second the y, the third is the width and the last the height. So, what you're saying by

```
CGRectMake(320, 568, 0, 120)
```

is "*make a rect at the bottom right corner, give it a zero width and make it 120 points tall*".
Does this make sense or you need more help about the coordinates?

Comment: thank you Irene. but the problem of myLocationButton on the bottom left corner is not solved. i want to place that button on top right corner. is it possible?

Comment: You accepted my answer so I guess your problem is solved now?